# Bootstrap Click photos to zoom in

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to click a photo, then it will zoom in.

Like this website --> https://mobirise.com/bootstrap-gallery/

But I just need one photo to zoom in only. Not a photo gallery. Please help.

```
<img src="images/uploads/phs.jpg"></img>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question currently doesn't explain what you have tried to solve your problem. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help.

Answer (score 5):

in my last project, i have used this i hope its help you try this demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/6CR2H/1/

```
<a href="#" class="pop">
    <img src="http://patyshibuya.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/04.jpg" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;" class="img-responsive">
</a>

<a href="#" class="pop">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;">
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" data-dismiss="modal">
    <div class="modal-content"  >              
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <img src="" class="imagepreview" style="width: 100%;" >
      </div> 
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
               <p class="text-left">1. line of description<br>2. line of description <br>3. line of description</p>

          </div>

      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript code:

```
 $(function() {
            $('.pop').on('click', function() {
                $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
                $('#imagemodal').modal('show');   
            });     
    });
```

Comment: This plugin also great works for me.

Bootstrap 3 lightbox plugin:http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/

Comment: Thank you Ankit. This helped me very much.